# size of nested dictionary and list

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have dictionary with following format:

Demo code:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(data)
{'lookup': {'F01': '\n.custom1 {\n    background-color: #f5e9dc;\n    padding: 10px;\n    border-radius: 10px;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-size: 0.9em;\n    margin-top: 1em;\n    }\n.custom2 .style8-rw {\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    color: #F57215;\n    }',
            'F02': '\n.custom1 {\n    background-color: #f5e9dc;\n    padding: 10px;\n    border-radius: 10px;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-size: 0.9em;\n    margin-top: 1em;\n    }\n.custom2 .style8-rw {\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    color: #F57215;\n    }',
            'F03': '\n.custom1 {\n    background-color: #f5e9dc;\n    padding: 10px;\n    border-radius: 10px;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-size: 0.9em;\n    margin-top: 1em;\n    }\n.custom2 .style8-rw {\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    color: #F57215;\n    }',
            'F04': '\n.custom1 {\n    background-color: #f5e9dc;\n    padding: 10px;\n    border-radius: 10px;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-size: 0.9em;\n    margin-top: 1em;\n    }\n.custom2 .style8-rw {\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    color: #F57215;\n    }',
            'F05': '\n.custom1 {\n    background-color: #f5e9dc;\n    padding: 10px;\n    border-radius: 10px;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-size: 0.9em;\n    margin-top: 1em;\n    }\n.custom2 .style8-rw {\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    color: #F57215;\n    }',
            'F06': '\n.custom1 {\n    background-color: #f5e9dc;\n    padding: 10px;\n    border-radius: 10px;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-size: 0.9em;\n    margin-top: 1em;\n    }\n.custom2 .style8-rw {\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    color: #F57215;\n    }',
            'F07': '\n.custom1 {\n    background-color: #f5e9dc;\n    padding: 10px;\n    border-radius: 10px;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-size: 0.9em;\n    margin-top: 1em;\n    }\n.custom2 .style8-rw {\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    color: #F57215;\n    }',
            'F08': '\n.custom1 {\n    background-color: #f5e9dc;\n    padding: 10px;\n    border-radius: 10px;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-size: 0.9em;\n    margin-top: 1em;\n    }\n.custom2 .style8-rw {\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    color: #F57215;\n    }',
            'F09': '\n.custom1 {\n    background-color: #f5e9dc;\n    padding: 10px;\n    border-radius: 10px;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-size: 0.9em;\n    margin-top: 1em;\n    }\n.custom2 .style8-rw {\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    color: #F57215;\n    }',
            'F10': '\n.custom1 {\n    background-color: #f5e9dc;\n    padding: 10px;\n    border-radius: 10px;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-size: 0.9em;\n    margin-top: 1em;\n    }\n.custom2 .style8-rw {\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    color: #F57215;\n    }',
            'F11': '\n.custom1 {\n    background-color: #f5e9dc;\n    padding: 10px;\n    border-radius: 10px;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-size: 0.9em;\n    margin-top: 1em;\n    }\n.custom2 .style8-rw {\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    color: #F57215;\n    }',
            'F12': '\n.custom1 {\n    background-color: #f5e9dc;\n    padding: 10px;\n    border-radius: 10px;\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-size: 0.9em;\n    margin-top: 1em;\n    }\n.custom2 .style8-rw {\n    font-family: sans-serif;\n    font-weight: bold;\n    color: #F57215;\n    }'},
 'sequence': ['F01',
              'F02',
              'F03',
              'F04',
              'F05',
              'F06',
              'F07',
              'F08',
              'F09',
              'F10',
              'F11',
              'F12']}
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(data)
136
>>> sys.getsizeof(data["sequence"])
80
>>> sys.getsizeof(data["lookup"])
520
>>>
```

I can not get how nested dictionary is store in memory because size if `data` is 136 bytes and size of `data["sequence"]` is 80 bytes and also size of `data["lookup"]` is 520 bytes.

Also when I do type casting of variable data from `dictionary` to `string` then size of string variable is `3587 bytes`.

Demo Code:

```
>>> data_str = str(data)
>>> sys.getsizeof(data_str)
3587
```

Can any on explain me why?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/449560

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dictionaries and lists store *references* (like every other standard container in Python). `sys.getsizeof()` doesn't follow references, it gives you the memory footprint of the C structure *only*. The references are C pointers; their size depends on your specific platform.

Converting a dictionary to a string recursively converts the contents to (`repr()`) strings too, so all those references are then dereferenced and included in the output. Note that this is not an accurate reflection of the memory size for the original object; strings contain characters, it depends on your exact Python version, OS and range of Unicode codepoints used how much memory each character takes, and the character count has a non-linear relationship to the actual object being reflected.

If you want to know the memory footprint of a dictionary *with the contents* you need to do so recursively. Take into account that a dictionary can contain references to itself (directly or indirectly), or that any object can have multiple references to it and should only be counted *once*. I'd use the [`id()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) to track what objects have already been handled.

There are already several posts on Stack Overflow that discuss calculating memory size for containers using recursion or other tools, see [Deep version of sys.getsizeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208410/deep-version-of-sys-getsizeof), [Python deep getsizeof list with contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117255/python-deep-getsizeof-list-with-contents), and [Memory-usage of dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579757/memory-usage-of-dictionary-in-python) for some examples.

Comment: 1. yes, Dictionary store references. how to get total size of nested dictionary? or we can get size by type casting to string?

Comment: @VivekSable: I already answer that. Recurse, but take into account that you can have circular references and objects stored multiple times. For example, a Python process only ever has **one** `None` object, so don't count it multiple times when you have `{'foo': None, 'bar': None, 'baz': None}`.

Comment: @VivekSable: and using `str()` is very far from an accurate reflection of the memory use.

Comment: I not refresh answer. Yes, `str()` is not best way to findout size of nested dictionary.

Comment: Another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316760