# Understanding python dictionary memory allocation

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to understand how much memory allocation behaves for dictionaries when deleting keys and adding new keys to them for the below example. (since this is a single long program I've grouped into sections- welcoming question edits if you felt non-readable)

**Example:**

```
d = {
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    "three": 3
}

import sys
def get_size(obj):
    return sys.getsizeof(obj)

#section 1
print("d - without modification: ")
print(d)
print(get_size(d))

#section 2
print("d - after deletion of two: ")
del d["two"]
print(d)
print(get_size(d))

#section 3
print("d - after adding two_copy key: ")
d["two_copy"] = 2
print(d)
print(get_size(d))

#section 4
print("d - after adding few values modification: ")
d["three_copy"] = 3
d["four"] = 4
print(d)
print(get_size(d))

#section 5
import copy
d1 = copy.deepcopy(d)
print("d1 - after deepcopy of d: ")
print(d1)
print(get_size(d1))
```

**Output:**

```
d - without modification: 
{'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'one': 1}
288

d - after deletion of two: 
{'three': 3, 'one': 1}
288

d - after adding two_copy key: 
{'two_copy': 2, 'three': 3, 'one': 1}
288

d - after adding few values modification: 
{'two_copy': 2, 'three_copy': 3, 'four': 4, 'three': 3, 'one': 1}
288

d1 - after deepcopy of d: 
{'two_copy': 2, 'three': 3, 'one': 1, 'four': 4, 'three_copy': 3}
288
```

In the above example, `section 1` is the normal one that we used to see.
For `section 2`, **why size here is same as before even removing a key from dictionary?**.
When we add new key to the `section 3`, it stays in the same size. But **why adding two more new keys in the same dictionary not increasing its size?** on `section 4`.

And when I add new key in `section 4`, the size of `section 4 and section 5` returns different values like this,

```
print("d - after adding few values modification: ")
d["three_copy"] = 3
d["four"] = 4
d["five"] = 5    # this is the newly added key
print(d)
print(get_size(d))
```

Output for *section 4 and section 5*:

```
d - after adding few values modification: 
{'two_copy': 2, 'three_copy': 3, 'one': 1, 'four': 4, 'five': 5, 'three': 3}
480
d1 - after deepcopy of d: 
{'two_copy': 2, 'three_copy': 3, 'one': 1, 'five': 5, 'four': 4, 'three': 3}
480
```

**Why size changes after adding one more new key on the same program?**

I've marked all my questions on **bold**. Please anyone help me to understand what's happening under the hoods? Thanks.

You can run the same program [here](https://onlinegdb.com/6iG-ta5vf).

Comment: Container sizes (dict, list, set) do not change every time the amount of elements change. That would have a huge overhead and cause a performance hit (imagine if every time you added a key to a dict  new memory was allocated and data had to be copied). Instead, Python uses a smart algorithm to determine when it is needed to change the memory allocated, and by how much.

Comment: Nice, can I get some reference of what you're mentioning here -  ```Python uses a smart algorithm to determine when it is needed to change the memory allocated, and by how much.```

Comment: Found well written answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65512841/11094041

Comment: @say_my_name the C code has excellent documentation if you want to dive into that. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c