# Does Python optimize key-value pairs with None values?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

Consider a dict with an int key and dict value, where the value features string keys and further dict values.

Now consider these 2 representations of this dict:

```
>>> a_it_1
{ 1: {"it": None, "ndar": {1:1}, 2: {"it": {2:8}, "ndar": None} }
>>> a_it_2
{ 1: { "ndar": {1:1}, 2: { "it": {2:8}} }
```

As you can see the inner dict is sparse; not all values appear in all keys.

`a_it_2` is excluding key-value pairs that include `None` values in an attempt to save memory.

This is a simple example, the actual dict contains more than 10,000 outer key-value pairs.

I am doing some debugging and can see that both these use the same amount of memory.

I am using:

```
round(asizeof.asizeof({...}) / (1024 * 1024), 2)
```

where the `...` represents the dict comprehension I am using to build the 2 dicts displayed above.

The `asizeof` method is from the [`asizeof`](https://pympler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/asizeof.html) module of Pympler.

I am including my dict comprehensions below.

Retaining the inner sparse key-value pairs but setting None values:

```
a_it_1 = {k: {p: vi if type(vi) == int or type(vi) == bool or len(vi) > 0 else None for p, vi in v.items() if vi is not None} for k, v in a_it.items() if k < 10000}
```

Removing the inner sparse key-value pairs completely:

```
a_it_2 = {k: {p: vi for p, vi in v.items() if vi is not None and (type(vi) == int or type(vi) == bool or len(vi) > 0)} for k, v in a_it.items() if k < 10000}
```

Taking the size of both these dicts using `asizeof` returns the same value: 12.3 (megabytes) each.

I would have expected the lack of the key-value pairs in the first place, to use less memory.

Does Python internally optimize key-value pairs with `None` values?

**Updated**

My question may not have been clear. And the question I posed was perhaps the wrong one.

My current a_it is using a lot of memory. I would like to optimize it.

I created 2 new versions of the dict based on the comprehensions above.

One includes the key-value pairs with None values; and the other ignores the key-value pairs completely.

I would like to know why they still use the same amount of memory. I accept that Python does not optimise key-value pairs with None values, because **it can't**.

But is there benefit to excluding the key value pairs for non-yet set values? My experiment did not prove this and I turned to the SO community for help.

Comment: Haven't you carefully demonstrated that (at least in the implementation you're using) it doesn't? Also consider the difference between e.g. `a_it_x[1]["it"]` in the two cases - at the very least, Python would have to maintain a list of all of the keys that _do_ exist but _don't_ have non-`None` values which seems like a lot of extra work (especially given the dictionary just contains _references_ to `None`, which are the same size as references to anything else).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512481/how-allocation-of-memory-for-dict-in-python-works

Comment: @jonrsharpe Re "Python would have to maintain a list of all of the keys that do exist but don't have non-None values" is this saying that Python doesn't need to store the string keys because they point to None values? and what do you mean by the "the dictionary just contains references to None"? it doesn't. some values are dicts as they would have been set, others would not have been set yet, and I am wondering whether to have the key-value pair for them or not (it seems obvious but the results did not support my thought-process)

Comment: @slothrop thanks for the link. it seems interesting, I was not aware that Python allocates memory in chunks for dicts. and my issue may be related. Part of the accepted answer: "Also, dictionary just stores a reference of memory that holds the keys and values, and doesn't stores key-value itself as part of dict object." I ran the tests in the same answer via Python 3.11, sure enough sys.getsizeof on {'a': 'a'} and {'a'*100000: 'a'*1000000} returns equal results, but asizeof returns the results pertaining to the actual referenced memory, and not just the size of the dict in memory

Comment: _"is this saying that Python doesn't need to store the string keys because they point to None values?"_ - no, precisely the opposite; even if it doesn't store the repeated references to None, to be able to know when it should return None and when it should throw a KeyError it still needs to know (and therefore store and update) which keys are considered present). And also no: some values are _references to_ dicts, which is why the "flat" getsizeof returns a smaller number than you expected and you're using asizeof to begin with.

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe. you are answering my main question but maybe I asked the wrong question. let me re-edit

Comment: The short answer to your new question is: we don't know. You've already demonstrated it makes no difference in storage terms (None is a singleton so only exists once anyway) so it would depend largely on access patterns. If you care about the difference between "missing" or "present but None-valued" then you can't. Maybe consistently getting a `KeyError` is better for you than e.g. `d.get(k) is None` but maybe you still need the latter for varying depth.

Comment: but what about the keys? they need to be stored to be linked with the singleton object. the presence versus the absence of a key; I would have expected less memory in the latter. does the fact that inner dicts all contain the same string keys, make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not, and it can't. Consider that there is a difference between

- the key **is** in the dictionary, and it has no value (`{"foo": None}`)
- the key **is not** in the dictionary, so the question about the value makes no sense (`{}`)

That is, simply put, `"foo" in mydict` will be `True` for `{"foo": None}`, and one needs to store that information.

If you're thinking about "sparse" dictionaries (which really isn't the right term here), you may want to look at "slotted dataclasses"; a `dataclass` using `__slots__` is usually much more memory efficient with respect to the key-set, as it has a known universe of possible keys.

When thinking about the *actual* memory requirements of two similar sized `dict` with similar content, it's important to keep in mind that

- `dict` [overcommits](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0c574540e07792cef5487aef61ab38bfe404060f/Objects/dictobject.c#L459) the key-space, in order to avoid having to rebalance the dict during frequent inserts. This means that two similar sized dictionaries (for some fuzzy "similar") will use the same amount of memory, erring on the upside.
- Strings in CPython are sometimes [`interned`](https://stackabuse.com/guide-to-string-interning-in-python/), if possible. This is true to all string literals that are present in the code. Since all interned strings use the same memory backing, the memory required by a second `dict` which can share a lot of the keys with the first dict only grows due to the str-objects themselves, which is very, very roughly pointer-sized.

Comment: this was clear to me outright. but your answer doesn't answer why I am getting the same size in memory, when one has more key value pairs than the other. my question on whether Python optimizes key-value pairs with None values may not have made much sense, but I am trying to find a reason why a dict that has more key-value pairs is using the same amount of memory as a dict that has less key-value pairs.

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri Dictionaries use a hash map. Baring collisions, etc, hash maps don't need to grow as you add keys to them. The values are represented with pointers to the values (Python has no primitives, everything is a pointer to an Object), and a None pointer takes up the same space as any other pointer.

Comment: @MatBailie so by my example, adding a key value pair, in the inner dict, with a string key and None value, does not use up memory?

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri, I misunderstood your question then. As you expect, an additional key does increase the memory requirement, wether the key points to `None` or any other object. However, `dict` does not grow strictly linearly with the number of keys, as it overcommits the key-space to avoid having to re-balance too often. That means that the memory required for a `dict` of 10,000 elements is probably exactly the same as a `dict` of 11,000 elements (or whatever). I don't know if Pympler is accurate in that regard. What is the actual size difference between `a_it_1` and `a_it_2`?

Comment: @user2722968 sys.getsizeof on {'a': 'a'} and {'a'*100000: 'a'*1000000} returns equal results, but asizeof returns the results pertaining to the actual referenced memory, and not just the size of the dict in memory. this is why I am using Pympler. I was not aware that dict assigns memory in chunks, and this may be related to the behaviour I am observing. it may also be possible that my sample set is too small to observe the difference. (btw, my initial question may not have been clear, and I re-edited it to reflect this)

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri, That's because both are dicts of just one entry; the strings are behind pointers. BTW, `{'a'*10000: 'a'*10000}` (depending on how you create it), only uses one (not two) allocations of `'a'*10000`, because the key and the value point to the same immutable string `'aaaa...'`. So how much memory is used by that dict? It's not trivial...
See [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0c574540e07792cef5487aef61ab38bfe404060f/Objects/dictobject.c#L459) for details on how dicts grow in size.

Comment: exactly the strings are behind pointers, and asizeof returns the memory size of the pointers, unlike sys.getsizeof. also, in the second example the key is 100_000 and the value is 1_000_000 - they are not the same on purpose. so I guess they are not the same immutable string, no? and with your example, how would Python refer to the same memory pointer? only because they would have been initialized together? (perhaps that's what you meant by depending on how you create it)

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri, strings are [`interned`](https://stackabuse.com/guide-to-string-interning-in-python/) in CPython, if possible. This affects things like class- and method-names, but also string literals. E.g. if you write `d = {'foobar': 'foo', 'barfoo': 'foo'}`, then `d['foobar'] is d['barfoo']` is `True`, because CPython allocates "foo" just once and reuses that allocation in both keys.

Comment: well than that is the answer. string interning also applies for the keys. Python is indeed optimising the usage of duplicate keys, by referring to the same memory pointer. this is the case at the point of initializing the dict, as well as when adding further keys and inner-dicts (I tested both). if an inner string key appears once, any duplicated keys refer to the same memory pointer, and are hence, only counted once by Pympler (this explains why my 2 dicts are using the same size in memory). Kind sir/miss, feel free to update your answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri, updated; feel free if this does in fact answer your question.

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri In response to "adding a string key with a None value doesn't use up memory?" The hash map has already preallocated the memory needed to add the references to the Key and the Value. Instant is ting the string will use memory, but not by the hash map. No memory is needed to instantiate a None, as there is already a global immutable object for None, and the map just points to that. (I suggest researching hash maps rather than asking endless questions.)

Comment: Your assertion that python is optimising duplicate keys is wrong. Python is optimising memory allocation of duplicate identical immutable objects, and that your use case is a subset of that behavior, but is had Nothing to do with dictionaries.

Comment: yes it is not specific to dict keys but it also applies to dict keys. I performed a test setting: a = "key1", b = "key1" and using "key1" in a dict, and in all cases, the memory ID is the same. I may not have been clear with my "assertion", but this does indeed clear up my confusion